# elasticsearch - partition data by date

Tags: elasticsearch

Due to maintenance reasons, I need to create partitioned index by date (split by each month).

For instance, suppose I would need to remove 10-2015 docs - I would just drop 10-2015 index.

Suppose I have that mapping:

```
PUT my_logs
{
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {  
      "properties": { 
        "data":    { "type": "string"  }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's important that data will be placed in the correct date without the need to create the same mapping above for a specific month.

What is the best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html), you can achieve what you want.

First you create an index template like the one below:

```
PUT /_template/my_logs
{
  "template": "logs-*",
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {  
      "properties": { 
        "data":    { "type": "string"  }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then every time you index a new document into an index whose name starts with `logs-` then this template will be applied at index creation time.

```
PUT /logs-10-2015/logs/7234t27
{ 
   "data": "some data"
}
```